# SIP (RFC 3261) server transactions timeout

Tags: transactions, sip

According to the [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.2), there is no timeout for server transactions in PROCEEDING or TRYING states. As I understand, that means that TU MUST send response to the transaction. However, if TU fails, there should be a way for transaction to know about that and terminate.

Which behavior is correct according to the [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.2)?

1. Should server transaction detect TU failure?
2. Should I add my own timeout? Assuming that client transaction on the other side will time-out anyway, it should be safe to terminate server transaction after some timeout > expected client transaction timeout.
3. Any other behavior?

Comment: There is no Trying state for a server INVITE transaction. Do you mean a _client_ INVITE transaction?

Comment: To be precise, I mean TRYING/PROCEEDING for non-INVITE server transaction and PROCEEDING for INVITE server transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeouts in the transactions are to handle *remote* failures - network partitions, the remote machine falling over, etc.

SIP doesn't tell you what to do in the event of a *local* failure, like your Transaction-User layer falling over.

Your TU's the "brain" of the entire SIP stack, so if it fails, your SIP stack fails as a whole. I don't think it's sensible for the transaction layer to attempt to continue functioning.

Some transactions might meaningfully persist across your application reboot - presence subscriptions, say - while others like calls probably can't. You might store the state of these "persistable" transactions on disk, and restore them after you restart your application.